# How to interpret curve of regularization loss during CNN training?

Tags: deep-learning, loss-function, object-detection, regularization

I am fine-tuning a single shot detector (SSD) in tensorflow object detection api.

I didn't freeze the backbone (mobilenet), I programmed the learning rate to go from e-3 to e-4 to e-5.

In the paper the loss function is the sum of a weighted l1 norm and a **weighted softmax**. But is the tensorflow object detection api, the default configuration uses a **weighted sigmoid** instead of a **weighted softmax**.

When I visualize training progress on tensorboard, I get a curve showing the progress of the regularization loss. Here are 2 different examples of curves I got (first image : when I used weighted softmax, second image : when I used weighted sigmoid):

[image: regularization loss when using weighted softmax]

[image: regularization loss when using weighted sigmoid]

How to interpret the progress of the regularization loss, is it bad when it is high?